# "t.data.data is undefined" in grafana

Tags: java, grafana, metrics, prometheus, micrometer

I'm new to micrometer, prometheus and grafana. I'm trying to run my first example with these three things working together. But I'm having a hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using micrometer's API to create a `PrometheusMeterRegistry` like this:

```
new PrometheusMeterRegistry(new PrometheusConfig() {
        @Override
        public Duration step() {
            return Duration.ofSeconds(10);
        }

        @Override
        @Nullable
        public String get(String k) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

And I'm creating a `HttpServer` as described here using the following code:

```
try {
            HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
            server.createContext("/prometheus", httpExchange -> {
                String response = prometheusMeterRegistry.scrape();
                httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.getBytes().length);
                try (OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody()) {
                    os.write(response.getBytes());
                }
            });

            new Thread(server::start).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

I configured Prometheus as my data-source in grafana and set the URL to `http://localhost:8080/prometheus`. But when I try creating a new dashboard and add a graph to it, I get a red exclamation mark saying `t.data.data is undefined`. And because of this I'm not able to view the graphs. The complete stack-trace is as follows:

```
kr</t.prototype.transform@http://localhost:3000/public/build/app.dfabdd44b3be44288eac.js:22:723420
jr</t.prototype.query/</<@http://localhost:3000/public/build/app.dfabdd44b3be44288eac.js:22:736135
qt@http://localhost:3000/public/build/vendor.dfabdd44b3be44288eac.js:9:5239
Wa@http://localhost:3000/public/build/vendor.dfabdd44b3be44288eac.js:9:40274
jr</t.prototype.query/<@http://localhost:3000/public/build/app.dfabdd44b3be44288eac.js:22:735858
c/</<@http://localhost:3000/public/build/vendor.dfabdd44b3be44288eac.js:130:92198
c/<@http://localhost:3000/public/build/vendor.dfabdd44b3be44288eac.js:130:92043
$digest@http://localhost:3000/public/build/vendor.dfabdd44b3be44288eac.js:130:97575
$apply@http://localhost:3000/public/build/vendor.dfabdd44b3be44288eac.js:130:99590
$applyAsync/r<@http://localhost:3000/public/build/vendor.dfabdd44b3be44288eac.js:130:99735
h@http://localhost:3000/public/build/vendor.dfabdd44b3be44288eac.js:130:33036
ln/this.$get</</i.defer/n<@http://localhost:3000/public/build/vendor.dfabdd44b3be44288eac.js:130:34396
```

The following is the screenshot of the error in grafana that I'm gettng:
[image]

Any suggestions what I might be missing?

Note: I can see timer getting published on native prometheus using URL `localhost:8080/prometheus`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8080 is your application server. You need to run a Prometheus server that scrapes this application, then you can use localhost:9090 as a datasource.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. Can you please also tell me where, in prometheus, we can configure this `localhost:9090` so that if I want to give a different `host:port` as data-source to grafana I can do that. I'm following [this](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/first_steps/) tutorial and starting my prometheus server using `./prometheus --config.file=prometheus.yml`. It will be great if you can point me to the list of all the standard options. Thanks!